# Does Cardano Node support chained transactions?

Tags: transaction, cardano-node

Does Cardano node supports processing of chained transactions?
E.g. we have an output [O1], and want to create a transaction [TX1] using [O1] as an input and creating new output [O2] and then, until [TX1] is confirmed in the network create [TX2] using [O2] as an input and creating new output [O3].

- Is Cardano node capable of handling this chain [TX1, TX2] properly? It has to lookup [O2] in mempool in order to verify TX2 is valid.
- Is it possible at all that [TX1, TX2] get into one block? Does the current block validation protocol allows that at all?

Answer (score 3):

No - as it would also opens a web of security issues, including deficiencies of accounting model - also, it enables a possibility to DDoS network for a small duration.

*Correction: Apparently you can do this already, it is just not easily made available to end-user facing tools yet.

Comment: What security issues are you talking about exactly? Bitcoin and Ergo have been successfully supporting this feature for quite a long time already - and no significant vulnerabilities were found in this approach so far. So what's special about Cardano here?
As fo DDoS, I guess the network can be DDoSed anyway and tx chaining doesn't make much difference here.

Comment: Oh, that's great. Can you elaborate on how can I do that? It's ok to use any Haskell SDK for me.